# SQL - positive part function (x)^+

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I want to get positive part of a number x in sql. It means that the result is x if x>0 and zero otherwise. I mean to use it after an aggregate function.

```
select 1 as num, 200 as weight into #table
insert into #table values
(8, 100),
(10, 200),
(11, -300),
(20, -100);
```

Till now I have been using the following:

```
select sum(num * weight)/sum(weight) as Result, 
       IIf(sum(num * weight)/sum(weight)>0, sum(num * weight)/sum(weight), 0) as PositivePartResult    
from #table
```

But it is not clear as the function gets longer. Is there a built-in function to get the same result without repetition of the formula?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? There is no `iif` in (standard) SQL

Comment: I am using SQL Server. The post by Mini shows equivalent query with the use of case when.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of writing same query is:

```
select Result,
       case when Result > 0 Then Result else 0 end as  PositivePartResult 
       from 
       (
          select sum(num * weight)/sum(weight) as Result       
          from #table
       )T
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either calculate the value inline or, if you'll be doing this frequently, create a user defined function:

```
create function PositiveValue( @N as Int )
  returns Int as
  begin
    return ( Sign( @N ) + 1 ) / 2 * @N;
  end;
go

declare @Samples as Table ( N Int );
insert into @Samples ( N ) values ( -42 ), ( -1 ), ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 42 );

select N, ( Sign( N ) + 1 ) / 2 * N as PositiveValue1, dbo.PositiveValue( N ) as PositiveValue2
  from @Samples;

-- drop function dbo.PositiveValue;
```